# Excluir datos duplicados de un array al realizar scraping web

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Tengo un codigo para que me realice un raspado a una pagina de sismos y luego me guarde los datos de los ultimos sismos ocurridos en un csv.

Si hago nuevamente el raspado y no hay datos nuevos estos se duplican, como logro hacer para que cuando realice el nuevo raspado no guarde los datos que ya estan en el csv?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

# Ejemplo de como imprimir todo
# print soup.prettify()

# Obtenemos la tabla

tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]

# Obtenemos todas las filas
rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")

output_rows = []
for row in rows:
    # obtenemos todas las columns
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    output_row = []
    if len(cells) > 0:
        for cell in cells:
            output_row.append(cell.text)
        output_rows.append(output_row)
        

with open('Sismos.csv', 'a', newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Comment: Qué has intentado

Comment: with open("Sismos.csv", "r") as f_in:
   unicos = set(f_in.readlines())
with open("output.csv", "w") as f_out:
   f_out.write("".join(unicos)) ahi ya no me los duplica, pero no quiero enerar otro csv quiero trabajar sobre el mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]
rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")
output_rows = []

with open("Sismos.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvfileread:
    sismos = list(csv.reader(csvfileread))

for row in rows:
    # obtenemos todas las columns
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    output_row = []
    if len(cells) > 0:
        for cell in cells:
            output_row.append(cell.text.strip())
# añadimos comprobación
        if not any(";".join(output_row) in sublist for sublist in sismos):
            output_rows.append(output_row)

# añadimos encoding utf8
with open('Sismos.csv', 'a', newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```